# Показать количество из списка

Tags: php, список

Есть файл и в нем данные. Мне нужно его разбить на части например по 10 штук и вывести в списке. Написал небольшую функцию вроде работает, но не выводит последние 10 как это исправить чето я запутался вообще.

```
$p = 1;

if(!empty($_GET['p']))
    $p = intval($_GET['p']);
// Полный путь к файлу
$file0 = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/arrays/file.log");

/*
file.log
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
...
Number 999
Number 1000
*/

// Количество показываемых данных на странице
$lstvars= 10;
// Считает сколько массивов в переменной
$score  = count($file0);

$pages = $score/10;

if($score > $lstvars){
    $sarray = "0";
    if($p > 1){
        $end = $p.$sarray;
        if($end > $lstvars){
            $start = $end - $lstvars;
            $sarray = $start;
        }
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < $lstvars; $i++) { 
        echo $file0[$sarray];
        $sarray =$sarray +1;
    }
}else{
    foreach ($file0 as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
echo "<br>";
for ($i=1; $i < $pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='?p=".$i."'>Page ".$i."</a> | ";
}
```

Comment: Извините,не смог откорректировать код

Comment: Толи я под вечер туго соображать начал, толи я вашу задачу не понял.

    $file_array = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/arrays/file.log");
    $file_parts = array_chunk($file_array, 10); // разбили массив на 10

Нужна, наример, третья страница, берем *$file_parts[3]* и выводим в цикле все данные.

Comment: Не мне нужно из массива сделать построчную навигацию 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,  и если я например нажму на 10 (page 10) то выведет количесто от 90 до 100, если например нажму на 7 то выведет c 60 по 70.  Ну проблему я решил добавив в $pages = $score/10+1; но за функцию спасибо. Если кто то может сократить ее киньте сюда.

Comment: > Не мне нужно из массива сделать построчную навигацию...

@jcmax, не поверите, но именно об этом я и говорил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тексту задачи...

```
//Чтение всего файла в массив
$file0 = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/arrays/file.log");    
//С какой позиции выводить
$start=(isset($_REQUEST['p'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['p']) : 0;
//Количество позиций на странице
$length=10;
//Количество страниц
$count=ceil(count($file0)/$length);

//Вывод из файла
for ($i = $start; $i <= $start+$length; $i++){ 
    if(!isset($file0[$i])) break;
    echo $file0[$i].'<br>';
}

//Разметка номеров страниц
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
    echo '<a href="?p='.($i*$length).'">'.($i+1).'</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
}
```

Данный подход плох тем, что необходимо весь текст файла перенести в массив... чревато при больших объемах текста.

Я бы посмотрел в сторону перемещения по файлу с помощью указателей и вывода только необходимых строк, хотя на вскидку и не помню, может ли указатель "прыгать" именно по строкам.

Критику ответа приветствую.

Comment: плюсанул. Только вот  когда я проверял как работает функция array_chunk(); у меня какой то бред выдавало. не понял и оставил старый код. а ваша функция куда короче и лудше наверно ее использовать. Спасибо